# Make hidden div appear then fade away?

Tags: jquery, html, css, fadeout

What is the simplest way to make a div appear then fade a way for a few second?

```
.fade_div {
    visibility: none;
    position: fixed;
    background-color: yellow;
    border: 1px solid black;
    top: 300px;
    left: 300px
}
```

```html
<input type="button" value="Add Item" id="mybutton">

<div class="fade_div">Successfully Added!</div>
```

```js
$('mybutton').click(function(){
    $('.fade_div').....
}
```

Comment: any reason to set `visibility` instead of display

Comment: @ArunPJohny using `visibility` means the space of the element is still taken into account for the width/height of parent elements. For `display: none` it is not. Although it should be `visibility: hidden` not `none`.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan that is the reason I asked since fixed position is used I don't think it matters

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The following code will make the elements with `.fade_div` class fade in quickly, wait one second (1000ms) and fade out slowly.

```
$('#mybutton').click(function(){
    $('.fade_div').finish().fadeIn("fast").delay(1000).fadeOut("slow");
});
```

You might want to stop using `visibility: hidden;` *(not none)* and use `display: none` instead.

For an instant appearance instead of fade in:

```
$('#mybutton').click(function(){
    $('.fade_div').finish().show().delay(1000).fadeOut("slow");
});
```

[**jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/itay1989/xgW2b/)

Comment: I'd use finish() too in case user click repeatedly on button: `$('.fade_div').finish().fadeIn("fast").delay(1000).fadeOut("slow");` BTW, finish() will clear the delay timeout, not like using stop() as i'm aware of

Comment: very nice, someone after you had a nice demo but they deleted their post, it's exactly what I'm trying to achieve but yours works just as good although fadeIn not necessarily required an instant appear would be nicer more responsive look.

Comment: "Object doesn't support property or method 'finish'" hmmm is jqueryUI required for this?

Comment: @Quaking-Mess No but it was added on jQuery 1.9. Maybe you're using an older version?

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#btn').click(function(e){    
    $('#fancy').fadeOut('slow', function(){
        $('#bank').fadeIn('slow');
    });
});
```

**[FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/vaibviad/3XwZv/906/)**

Answer (score 0):

Such a straight question:

use:

```
$(".fade_div").fadeOut(1500, someFunctionCallAfterFadeDone);
```

Read more about it [here](http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/)