# hide and show element(toggle) only for some time and then fade away

Tags: jquery, html, toggle, hide, fade

I need to hide a div with a link inside the div. At first, it is still visible  and undo link allows to undo that action. If no undo action is taken in the range of 1.5-3 seconds the tile fades away.
This is what I have tried:
http://jsfiddle.net/2jexgo3m/7/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title></title>

<style>
.metricsTile {
    width:275px;
    height:275px;
    border:1px solid #000;
}
.heading {
    width:275px;
    height:30px;
    border-bottom:1px solid #000;
}
.title {
    width:230px;
    float:left;
     border:1px solid #000;
}
.hideTile {
    width:25px;
    float:left;
    padding-left:5px;
    border:1px solid #000;
}
.content {
    width:275px;
}
.hideTile {
    font-size:13px;
}
.hidden {
    display:none;
}
.undoHide {
    display:none;
}
</style>
<script>
    $(function() {
        var hide = $('.undoHide').data('hidden'); 
            $("div.hideTile").click(function () {
            $(this).closest('.metricsTile').find('.content').hide();
            if ($('.undoHide').css('display') == 'none') {
                $(".undoHide").css("display","block");
                hide = $('.undoHide').data('hidden',true); 
            }        
            $(".title").html("Hidden");
            $(".undoHide").click(function () {
                $('.content').show();
                $(".undoHide").css("display","none");
                $('.title').html('BUSINESS');
                hide = $('.undoHide').data('hidden',false);  
           });

          if( $('.undoHide').attr("data-hidden") == 'true' )  {
           setTimeout(function() {   //calls click event after a certain time
           $('.metricsTile').fadeOut().remove();
           }, 3000);  
        }  
        });
    });
</script>
</head>
<body id="index" class="home">
<div class="metricsTile">
    <div class="heading">
        <div class="title">TITLE</div>
        <div class="hideTile">hide</div>       
   </div>
    <div class="content">
        <p>Description and Images</p>
    </div>
    <div class="undoHide" data-hidden="">Undo</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The fading away part is not working.

This question on SO looks similar but is not helping in my case.
[Make hidden div appear then fade away?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18812948/make-hidden-div-appear-then-fade-away)

Any help to make me understand where I am making the mistake is appreciated.

Comment: Why is the link you provide not helpful ?

Comment: Because, the fading away part should not happen if we click the undo link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it with clearTimeout(), also you had some understanding problems.

This Part here would never be true:

```
if( $('.undoHide').attr("data-hidden") == 'true' )  {
       setTimeout(function() {   //calls click event after a certain time /> Hmm, no click event in here...
       $('.metricsTile').fadeOut().remove();
       }, 3000);  
    }
```

It is called on page load once, so you have to check it on click:

```
$(function () {
    var timeout;
    $("div.hideTile").click(function () {
        $(this).closest('.metricsTile').find('.content').hide();
        $('.undoHide').show();
        $(".title").html("Hidden");
        timeout = setTimeout(function () { //calls fadeout after a time
            $('.metricsTile').fadeOut(function(){
                $(this).remove();
            });
        }, 3000);

    });

    $(".undoHide").click(function () {
        clearTimeout(timeout);
        $('.content').show();
        $(".undoHide").hide();
        $('.title').html('BUSINESS');
    });
});
```

here the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/jvhjqcfu/
hope it helps

Comment: I read about the clearTimeout() method just now. It makes so much sense to use it. Thanks so much!

Comment: youre welcome, also stay in line, you used .show(), but then in next line you used css("display", "none").. just .hide()...

Comment: Yes, the code was very clumsy, I appreciate your advice. I will improve my coding skills. Thanks!